# Is Firebase Cloud Storage security rule checked on upload start or upload complete?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

Suppose a file took a long time to be uploaded, and relevant `canUpload` value in firestore changed to false during this period, would the upload be successful?

If I have rules like this:

```
allow create : if firestore.get(user/$(request.auth.id)).canUpload
```

Answer (score 2):

Firebase security rules for Cloud Storage uploads are triggered **after** the payload has been received on the server (as it has access to metadata about the payload), but before the data is actually committed to storage itself.

It *is* indeed possible for the rules to change between starting the upload and completing it, in which case only the new, updated rules will be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the upload would continue, this is because Firestone rules are only checked when the operation is initiated, and not continuesly throughout the upload.